# GKE-On-Prem Installation

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to install GKE on-Prem and stuck at installing "Creating your admin workstation" stage.

Below is the error I am getting. I tried so many times with different user permission with my service account but no success.

> service account: nuage
>
> [root@cloudsdk gcp]# ./gkeadm create admin-workstation
> --auto-create-service-accounts Using config file "admin-ws-config.yaml"... Running preflight validations...
>
> Validation Category -  Tools SUCCESS- gcloud SUCCESS- ssh SUCCESS-
> ssh-keygen SUCCESS- scp
>
> Validation Category - Config Check SUCCESS - Config
>
> Validation Category: SSH Key SUCCESS- SSH key path
>
> Validation Category: Internet Access SUCCESS - Internet access to
> required domains
>
> Validation Category: GCP Access FAILURE - Read access to GKE on-prem
> GCS bucket: The provided gcp.whitelistedServiceAccountKeyPath
> "/root/gcp/smart-spark-288403-00292357e252.jss to read from GCS:
> Failed to get object attributes of
> gs://gke-on-prem-release/admin-appliance/1.4.1-gke.1/gke-on-prem-admin-appliance-vsphere-1.4.1-706@smart-spark-288403.iam.gserviceaccount.com
> does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage
> object., forbidden
>
> Validation Category- vCenter SUCCESS -Credentials SUCCESS -Version
> SUCCESS -Datacenter SUCCESS -Datastore SUCCESS -Resource Pool SUCCESS
> -Folder SUCCESS -Network SUCCESS -Datadisk
>
> Some validation results were FAILURE or UNKNOWN. Check report above.
> Exit with error: Failed to create and prepare admin workstation:
> preflight check failed

These are the roles currently attached with the service account:

```
Cloud Asset Service Agent
Owner
Storage Admin
Storage Object Admin
Storage Object Viewer
Viewer
```

Comment: can you tell are you able to setup gke on -prem if yes please tell me your machine cofiguration

Answer (score 0):

How did you mention the resource pool in admin-ws-config.yaml.
also you will have to try this command

```
gcloud iam service-accounts keys create whitelisted-key.json --iam-account <id>@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```